# Check if label exists (rather than selector) in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

According to the CasperJS documentation, you can check to see if a selector [`exists`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exists).

```
if (this.exists('#my_super_id')) {
    this.echo('found #my_super_id', 'INFO');
}
```

You can put any CSS3 selector in place of `#my_super_id`, and it works wonderfully. But, this isn't very useful if you want to click a specific button with a generic class.

```
<div class="btn button">Save</div>
```

The command [`clickLabel`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clicklabel) works very well in these cases, but I have not found a way to check if a label exists before clicking it.

```
// This doesn't work, for obvious reasons

if (this.labelExists('Save')) {
    this.clickLabel('Save');
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please don't include solutions in the question. You can post an answer yourself. I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath is your friend (or you could iterate over all elements on the page).

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;

casper.labelExists = function(labelText, tag){
    tag = tag | "*";
    return this.exists(x("//"+tag+"[text()='"+labelText+"']"));
};
```

This creates a function on the `casper` object that you can reuse and it works in exactly the same way as [`clickLabel`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L486).

Comment: I reached a similar xPath conclusion just as you posted. Thanks!